# 554, b'Transaction failed: Nested group in sending email using Amazon Aws SES

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ses

I want to send email from my Ubuntu server thru Amazon AWS SES. I've a working code and it's able to send an email.

However when I wrap the working code within a function it's giving this error:

```
Something with SMTP went wrong...
(554, b'Transaction failed: Nested group')
```

I'm attaching visual code comparison, .. I'm curious as to what could be wrong.

[image]

Comment: Did you find out why? I have the same error and it doesn't seem like it's documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

AWS SES has very strict checks on the message format. I don't know what your real data was but I encountered this with messages which happened to be wrapped so that the first character of the line was a period, which [has special meaning in SMTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-4.5.2). You're supposed to escape those leading periods by prefixing them with an extra period which the receiving server will strip, but rather than doing so manually I would highly recommend instead letting the Python standard library's [`email.message` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) do all of the work for you since that'll handle this problem and similar things like line-wrapping, using the appropriate encoding for non-ASCII data, etc. and it's less code:

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL


def send_test_email(smtp_params, from_address, to_address, subject, body):
    server_port = int(smtp_params["SMTP_PORT"])

    message = EmailMessage()
    message.set_content(body)
    message['To'] = to_address
    message['From'] = from_address
    message['Subject'] = subject

    with SMTP_SSL(smtp_params["SMTP_HOSTNAME"], port=server_port) as server:
        server.set_debuglevel(1)
        server.login(smtp_params["SMTP_USERNAME"], smtp_params["SMTP_PASSWORD"])
        server.send_message(message)
        server.quit()
```